# How to define rules in protégé

Tags: ontology, protege

I am trying to create an ontology for Cognitive Robotics Manipulation using protégé. I want to deduct from the ontology which robot can perform which task. To perform a task, the robot must be free. For example: to move an object, if a robot can lift that object and he is free so he can move the object. While doing the task, the robot is not free anymore. But the property free is variable so is there a way to define it in the ontology?

Robot(?r), MovingObject(?x), ActsOnObject(?x,?y), MovableObject(?y), has_weight(?y,?w1), Payload(?r,?w2), greaterThan(?w2,?w1),freeRobot(?r,true)->CanExecutes(?r,?x)